# batch file searching for *.bak in all subdir, getting modifydate and if modifydate = 30 (end of month) gopy file to newPath

Tags: batch-file

Im a damn noob in .cmd scripts :( i know how to find all my *.bak files but i have no idea how to get the modifydate of the file and if the modify date is the 30th of the month then copy it to a new directory... im trying to build my own archive system that every end o month "dump" (from my database) is copied to a differnet folder (not delete by the dump-script)

Can someone help me ? i really dont get this with the .cmd programming :(

detailed:

Directory: "D:Test"
Search in D:Test trought all subdirecotries and find all *.bak files -> if the *.bak file has a modifydate of 30 (or 31) or better "end of the month".. then copy the file to D:Test\archive\

Would be soooooooooooooo nice if someone could help me ... Thanks a lot

--> sorry for my bad english :)

Regards, Dominic

Comment: Case is solved... but thanks a lot :) Have a nice day

Comment: Please post your solution to this question as an aswer

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a command that selects files by date. Type

```
forfiles /?
```